# Unable to install EAR which have EJB 2.0 and EJB 3.0 in Web Sphere 8.0

Tags: ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I am facing an issue while installing EAR in web sphere 8.0 from admin console.
My EAR have two EJB jars and two Web wars.
The the EJB jar-1 & web war-1 are compiling with java 1.4 version and the EJB jar-2 & web war-2 are compiling with java 1.6 version.

But while installing EAR in the server i am getting an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

I am working with RAD tool, if i add EAR to the server in RAD tool itself and starting the server there is no issue.

I am bit confusing why the server is throwing this exception while installing EAR from Admin console. I am attaching the Stack trace of the Exception.

Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

```
12/10/13 17:43:00:857 IST] 00000022 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [AppInstallStatusServlet]: Initialization successful.
[12/10/13 17:43:11:868 IST] 0000002f annotations   E   CWWAM0001E: An exception occurred during annotation processing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'unknown-ejb-refs' is not a valid feature
[12/10/13 17:43:11:884 IST] 0000002f annotations   E   CWWAM0001E: An exception occurred during annotation processing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'annotated-classes' is not a valid feature
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.common.CommonPlugin$Implementation.loadClass(CommonPlugin.java:198)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.common.CommonPlugin.loadClass(CommonPlugin.java:98)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.util.DefaultEcoreBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultEcoreBuilder.java:54)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:205)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createEcoreBuilder(XMLHandler.java:2822)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.<init>(XMLHandler.java:397)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXXMLHandler.<init>(SAXXMLHandler.java:44)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.makeDefaultHandler(XMLLoadImpl.java:310)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:141)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:179)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.IBMDataModelImpl.forceMETADataResource(IBMDataModelImpl.java:591)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.IBMDataModelImpl.forceMETAData(IBMDataModelImpl.java:521)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.IBMDataModelImpl.forceEJBMETAData(IBMDataModelImpl.java:513)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.persistAMMData(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:377)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.merge(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:284)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:132)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:64)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.processManagedBeansAnnotations(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1351)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getManagedBeansDeploymentDescriptor(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1167)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getManagedBeansDeploymentDescriptor(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1042)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getManagedBeansDeploymentDescriptor(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1035)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.ManagedBeansHelper.getAllManagedBeansID(ManagedBeansHelper.java:127)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.ArchiveDeploymentInfo.getManagedBeansID(ArchiveDeploymentInfo.java:1582)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.ResourceGroupHelper.skipBndForManagedBeans(ResourceGroupHelper.java:493)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.utils.GetAllResourceRefs.addResRefs(GetAllResourceRefs.java:321)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.utils.GetAllResourceRefs.addResRefs(GetAllResourceRefs.java:270)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.utils.GetAllResourceRefs.addResRefs(GetAllResourceRefs.java:250)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.utils.GetAllResourceRefs.execute(GetAllResourceRefs.java:168)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.BindEarCmd.bindResourceRefs(BindEarCmd.java:1026)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.dfltbndngs.BindEarCmd.bind(BindEarCmd.java:285)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.ArchiveDeploymentInfo.createDefaultBindings(ArchiveDeploymentInfo.java:776)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.handlePreferences(AppDeploymentController.java:503)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.<init>(AppDeploymentController.java:352)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.<init>(AppDeploymentController.java:281)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:137)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:91)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.ResourceValidationHelper.<init>(ResourceValidationHelper.java:214)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateResourceTask.performTask(ValidateResourceTask.java:124)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:312)
[12/10/13 17:43:11:681 IST] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:737)
[12/10/13 17:43:53:819 IST] 0000002f webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer addExtensionFactory SRVE0239I: Extension Factory [class com.ibm.ws.soa.sca.web.extension.SCAWebExtensionFactory] was registered successfully.
[12/10/13 17:43:53:819 IST] 0000002f webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer addExtensionFactory SRVE0240I: Extension Factory [class com.ibm.ws.soa.sca.web.extension.SCAWebExtensionFactory] has been associated with patterns [""].
[12/10/13 17:43:54:022 IST] 0000002f WebSphereSCAS I   Added Servlet mapping: /dojo
[12/10/13 17:43:54:022 IST] 0000002f WebSphereSCAS I   Added Servlet mapping: /dojo
[12/10/13 17:43:54:022 IST] 0000002f WebSphereSCAS I   Added Servlet mapping: /tuscany
[12/10/13 17:43:54:022 IST] 0000002f WebSphereSCAS I   Added Servlet mapping: /tuscany
[12/10/13 17:43:58:645 IST] 0000002f annotations   E   CWWAM0001E: An exception occurred during annotation processing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'annotated-classes' is not a valid feature
[12/10/13 17:43:58:692 IST] 0000002f annotations   E   CWWAM0001E: An exception occurred during annotation processing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'unknown-ejb-refs' is not a valid feature
```

Comment: This is a product defect.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this seem to be addressed in latest fixpacks so you may want to apply latest fixpack 9 on your runtime WAS and see if that helps.

Link to fixpack : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27004980#ver80
VT
Note : opinions are my own and not those of my employer